# Unable to preduction right values from my Regression Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Predicting head poses to get output in the form of roll pitch yawn by using the model in the image, but the result is not accurate. Dataset has a total of 5500 images

- **What values should be:**

  - Roll: 0.67°
  - Pitch: -4.89°
  - Yaw: 22.57°
- **Values from my model:**

  - Roll: 356.10°
  - Pitch: 1036.82°
  - Yaw: 532.35°

`

```
#opening the  dataset
a,b,c,d = pkl.load(open('samples.pkl', 'rb'))

#concatenating the 2 arrays
x = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
y = np.concatenate((c,d), axis=0)


#Assigning degrees to roll pitch and yaw
roll, pitch, yaw = y[:, 0], y[:, 1], y[:, 2]

#test and train division
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
x_val, x_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(x_test, y_test, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

print(x_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(x_val.shape, y_val.shape)
print(x_test.shape, y_test.shape)

#standazing the test and train sets
std = StandardScaler()
std.fit(x_train)
x_train = std.transform(x_train)
x_val = std.transform(x_val)
x_test = std.transform(x_test)

BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 100

#model of cnn
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=20, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2', input_dim=x.shape[1]))
model.add(Dense(units=10, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer='l2'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='linear'))

print(model.summary())


#compiling the model
callback_list = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=25)]
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
hist = model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=callback_list)



model.save('model.h5')
```

`

Comment: Come on, there's not a single convolution layer I see.

Comment: help me out please

Comment: What you're doing in the first place? post full code. How you are passing the inputs to the model?

Comment: Updated my post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all predicting head poses from images is not a basic regression problem, it is, in fact, a computer vision problem that needs some computer vision-based approach.

Your model is a dummy MLP that will never perform well with the given problem.

I'm giving you some pointers, you still need to figure out which one works based on experimentation.

1. Instead of using an MLP, start with a ConvNet. Here's a simple CNN for regression.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same',
                 input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3))
```

2. Get rid of the Flatten, and use Global Pooling if the model overfits.
3. Try to normalize your output. Instead of blindly regressing, range the roll, pitch to 0 - 1 using min-max normalization. Use sigmoid in the last layer in this case.

Here's a paper to get the basic idea and start with a baseline model: https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4982509